# how to custom pagination in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-4, laravel-3

I have a pagination in view but the problem is i have so many items that mans a big pagination  like this [image]

what i want is display 1 2 3 ... 6 7 for example i tried to do it but i didn't found any thing,

**This is my action :**

```
public function index()
{
    // get all the logs
    $logs = DB::table('services')
        ->join('logs', 'services.id', '=', 'logs.service_id')
        ->paginate(20);
    // load the view and pass the logs
    return View::make('logs.index',array('logs'=> $logs,'title'=>'Service Logs'));
}
```

**This is my view :**

```
   <div class="container">
    @foreach($logs as $key => $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $value->domain }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->service_port }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->checktime }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                @if( $value->status == 'up' ) <img src="../img/up3.png" />
                @elseif( $value->status == 'down' ) <img src="../img/down3.png" />
                @else <img width="30" height="30" src="../img/warning_icon.png" />
                @endif
            </td>
            <td>{{ $value->response_time }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
  </div>
 {{$logs->links();}}
```

So i tried everything to do that so please if someone has any idea i will be very appreciative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Laravel will use "sliding" page numbers, however, it requires a minimum of 13 pages before it will create the "sliding" page numbers. If you have less than 13 pages it will default to an ordinary range of pages.

Unfortunately this number is hard coded into Laravel.

See [this comment (v4.1.24)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.1.24/src/Illuminate/Pagination/Presenter.php#L71) in the `Presenter` class that is responsible for building the pages.

Comment: Yes it works for more than 13 it so enough for me, thanks Jason i am really appreciate you 2 answers :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use your own view:

config/view.php

```
'pagination' => 'my-pagination',
```

view/my-pagination.php

```
<?php
$presenter = new Illuminate\Pagination\BootstrapPresenter($paginator);
$interval = 3;
$numberPages = $paginator->getLastPage();
$currentPage = $paginator->getCurrentPage();

if ($numberPages > 1)
{

    ?>
    <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
        <?php
        if ($numberPages <= $interval)
        {
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $numberPages; $i++)
            {

                ?>
                <li class="<?php echo $i == $currentPage ? ' active' : ''; ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo $paginator->getUrl($i); ?>" ><?php echo $i; ?></a>
                </li>
                <?php
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ($currentPage < $interval)
            {
                if ($currentPage > 1)
                {

                    ?>
                    <li class="prev">
                        <a href="{{ $paginator->getUrl($paginator->getCurrentPage()-1) }}">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $interval; $i++)
                {

                    ?>
                    <li class="<?php echo $i == $currentPage ? ' active' : ''; ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo $paginator->getUrl($i); ?>" ><?php echo $i; ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            elseif ($currentPage > ($numberPages - ($interval - 1)))
            {

                ?>
                <li class="prev">
                    <a href="{{ $paginator->getUrl($paginator->getCurrentPage()-1) }}">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <?php
                for ($i = ($numberPages - ($interval - 1)); $i <= $numberPages; $i++)
                {

                    ?>
                    <li class="<?php echo $i == $currentPage ? ' active' : ''; ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo $paginator->getUrl($i); ?>" ><?php echo $i; ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            else
            {

                ?>
                <li class="prev">
                    <a href="{{ $paginator->getUrl($paginator->getCurrentPage()-1) }}">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <?php
                for ($i = ($currentPage - 1); $i <= ($currentPage + 1); $i++)
                {

                    ?>
                    <li class="<?php echo $i == $currentPage ? ' active' : ''; ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo $paginator->getUrl($i); ?>" ><?php echo $i; ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }
            }
        }
        if ($paginator->getLastPage() > $paginator->getCurrentPage())
        {

            ?>
            <li class = "next"><a href = "{{ $paginator->getUrl($paginator->getCurrentPage()+1) }}" class = "{{ ($paginator->getCurrentPage() == $paginator->getLastPage()) ? ' disabled' : '' }}">
                    <i class = "fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
                </a></li>
            <?php
        }

        ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
}

?>
```